# Error 20009 (severity 9): Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist OS error 111, "Connection refused"

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, raspberry-pi4, freetds

I tried to connect to MSSQl database using freetds, unixODBC in raspberry pi 4.Below are my settings.

```
[fred]
  host = 109.*.*.*    # Remote Sql Server's IP addr
  port = 1433         # this is default
  tds version = 7.4     # this is by the time i post this
  client charset =UTF-8

[test]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = MSSQL Server
Trace = No
Server = fred      # IP or host name of the Sql Server
Port = 1433           # This is default
TDS_Version = 7.4

[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount=1
```

I have tested with tsql -H ip -U username -P password but the error still persists. I have also installed pyodbc. I am trying to connect from Pi to MS SQl Server Management studio. Could anyone suggest me to have a successful connection to database? I appreciate all the approaches.

Comment: _I am trying to connect from Pi to MS SQl Server Management studio._ Well that's not going to work. SSMS is a client application to manage SQL Server instances and databases. SSMS doesn't host any databases so you can't connect to it like that. Do you have a SQL Server instance installed somewhere? That's what you need to connect to.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am trying to connect to this server instance. But it just says the connection is refused. I can ping this server ip address from pi but once I try to connect, it keeps showing me connection is refused.

Comment: Do you have access to the target server (e.g.: physical access, or Remote Desktop)? Can you open the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager on it and confirm in the Server Protocols area that: a) the TCP/IP protocol is enabled, b) inside the TCP/IP protocol settings that it's listening on a publicly-accessible IP address (not just localhost, 127.0.0.1 or ::1) and c) that it's actually listening on port 1433? Is Windows Firewall configured to allow connections to it from remote client addresses? Are they also hardware firewalls on the network between you and the target server?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to shrug off this error by using the following call:

```
bsqldb -S $servername:1433 -D $databasename -U $username -P $password -i $inputfile
```

As far as documentation states, a qualified server name with the port number allows to bypass the related .conf settings.